# Using Azure Encryption for a Linux IaaS VM and its attached hard disks

Tags: linux, azure, encryption, centos, azure-keyvault

I had gone through this [URL](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/azure-security-disk-encryption/) which says how to Encrypt the Linux VM, but it does not seem to suit my requirement..

I have a Azure Linux VM(CentOS) that runs Elastic Search and I need to encrypt the data stored in the attached hard disks. And I do not make use of AD.

Are there proper steps that say how to do this, and also using Key Vault ?

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with the same task currently. You need an AD to create an Application inside, this application needs access to the KeyVault. Azure uses the Application for authorization.

A KeyVault can be created without AD, but it seems to be useless without AD.